# Oracle dataBase, what happend on Delete

Tags: database, hibernate, oracle11g, delete-row

I've got a problem like this: there is a big table of records connected by FK to three other. Once a day there is timer witch has a task to delete some rows defined by date and some string. Timer is some kind of hibernate solution. There is three instances of this timer witch approximately at one time begin to work.

What is happening when three timers concurrency fire and try execute:

```
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate(
            "DELETE FROM Data WHERE type= ? AND date< ? AND rownum <= ?", new Object[] { host, date, limit });
```

Limit is set to some kind of number like: limit *100 < select count(*) from Data where type='x' AND date<'y'.

I'd like to know what is happening from db point view.

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what you are asking?  There are lots of things going on in the database.  Are you trying to trace how individual blocks are read and dirtied, how redo and undo is generated, what is in the redo and undo that is generated?  Are you trying to understand how Hibernate causes the statement to be parsed and executed with the appropriate bind variable values?  Something else?

Comment: @JustinCave: I think the question is about three queries running the exact same `delete ... where rownum < X` concurrently. I don't know how locking works in the case, and not sure how many rows will get deleted (assuming that there are more than `X` to begin with).

Comment: I'd like to now how DB locks rows, what is happening when three task try to execute delete with the same user and date. I'm receiving SQLTimeout and I'd like to know why. Deleting ex 100 rows take like 3s, timeout is 10s.@Mat Exactly.